# Can we use argcomplete to do bash tab completion without writing the python keyword in the shell?

Tags: python, bash, shell, argparse

So I want to implement tab completion using `argcomplete` but I don't want to run the python script every time I want to do a completion.

I don't want it to be like:

```
python script-name.py --options<TAB>
```

Instead I want it to be something like:

```
--options<TAB>
arguments<TAB>
```

So like is it possible to do so using `argcomplete` or any python libraries.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Re: "I don't want to run the python script": By "run" do you mean "type the name of"?

Comment: Complete on something like --options' doesn't make sense; that could be an argument flag for almost any script.  If `script-name.py` is executable (bash permissions) and starts with `#!python`, `bash` can deduce that you want to use `python`.  You'd have to look at `argcomplete` docs to see if it can handle that case.  So for `argcomplete` to work you need to two things - the script and a way of identifying `python`.